# Unix find script feature improvement

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix, find

Below is a simple script that searches for files older than 30 days, then returns the number of files, or ZERO.

I'd like it to do the following, if possible:

- exit from the loop if it finds anything older than 30 days, and moves to the next line in list.dat

This way, it won't have to recurse further through someone's directory since we've found what we're looking for, as some of these directories are huge and we're using an aging SAN so it's glacial.

We're basically trying to generate a report of 'home' folders that have been idle for more than 30 days, but cannot extract this info via any other way than this.

I don't believe there is any way to capture the exit status of 'find' to make this any easier...

Or, if anyone has a suggestion on how to do this differently, I'm all ears.

Any suggestions, ideas or help much appreciated!

Dan

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin export PATH
SOURCEDIR=/Volumes/UserHomes/

while IFS= read -r line

do

  COUNT=$(find $SOURCEDIR/$line -type f -mtime -30 | wc -l)
  if [ "$COUNT" -eq 0 ]; then
     echo $line ZERO
  else
     echo $line $COUNT files found
  fi

done < $SRCLIST
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `-quit` option to `find`'s command line; it quits once the first matching file is found. You'll have to add `-print` to make sure the found name is printed.

With this you could simplify your expression:

```
if [ -n  "$(find ${SOURCEDIR}/${line} ... -print -quit)" ] ; then
  echo "Something found in ${line}!"
fi
```

Here's a minimal proof-of-concept example that shows the idea.

```
# get us an empty dir
mkdir find-example
cd find-example

# create / freshen a few files
touch foo bar baz

# create a subdir with a matching file
mkdir -p nested
touch nested/quux

# finds four files:
find . -type f -mtime -30
# prints:
# ./foo
# ./nested/quux
# ./baz
# ./bar

# finds only one file and stops
find . -type f -mtime -30 -print -quit

# prints:
# ./foo
# and exits.
```

The above is reporoducible on GNU/Linux, specifically Ubuntu 12.04.

I can imagine that `find` might fork to speed up scanning subdirectories in parallel, and other searching processes might continue for some time after `-quit` has been ecountered in one of them; `man 1 find` explicitly states that `-quit` ends all subprocesses, but this might not happen instantly. This is only my speculation; I did not test it on large trees, nor did I look at the source. I never saw `find` continue recursive descent after `-quit`. I never tried it on OSX or BSD + GNU findutils. YMMV.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I don't think find has a -quit option -- at least it's not in the man page and it doesn't work. Unless I have this wrong:  if [ -n "$(find ${SOURCEDIR}/${line} -type f -mtime -30 -quit)" ] ; then

Comment: I've updated my answer to make sure it's more bulletproof. It did contain an overlooked detail: with `-quit`, you need `-print`.

Comment: @Doug BSD find doesn't seem to have -quit, but this is really what you want. If it is an option, you can install the GNU version on OSX via homebrew.

Comment: @9000 thanks, that did it. I needed the GNU findutils, easily installed via MacPorts. That together with your string got me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a million! PS, why -quit isn't built into the BDS find (or CentOS) is beyond me! Cheers.

Comment: @9000 actually I spoke too soon. It still recurses through even after it's found a file that meets the criteria.

Comment: @Doug: It seems that `find` might fork to search subdirectories in parallel. But anyway I'm trying it on Linux; if I have chance I'll test it on a BSD system. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you pipe to head -1 and then wc -l this should terminate the command once you find the first file

```
COUNT=$(find $SOURCEDIR/$line -type f -mtime -30 | head -1 | wc -l)
```

This will return a count of 1 if a file was modified less than thirty days ago